# Why does our Windows service app's TCP connection fail with "Unable to read data from the transport connection... closed by the remote host."?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, sockets, tcp, tcpclient

I have a WCF based windows service that reads from an external device (scale) via a TCP connection.
A connection is made to the device when the service initially starts up.
This is the code we use to initiate the connection to the device:

```
scaleData.Client = New TcpClient(ipAddress, (portNumber))
scaleData.Stream = scaleData.Client.GetStream()
```

The service is hosted as a Windows service (as opposed to through IIS).

We have two applications that pull data from the WCF service,
an asp.net application and a winforms application.

The request returns data from the stream to the caller/client.

```
Try
                    Dim bytes As Int32 = scaleData.Stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length)
                    responseData = Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes)c
 Catch ex As IOException
                    exceptionMsg = String.Format("IOEXCEPTION!!! :: {0}", ex.Message)
End Try
```

Both the (winforms) test application, web application and windows service all reside on the same Windows 7 machine.

For the most part, this configuration works fine. But occasionally it fails.(we can't quite determine the pattern to it or specifics to it's occurrence) **with the following message**:

```
Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

Upon failure, we now added retry logic to try to reestablish the TCP connection and read from the stream, but that doesn't seem to fix the issue. I've also got logging enabled which captures the exceptions to a log file. All the log shows is the above mentioned message.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what is going on here?
Is this a Firewall/Port/virus scanner issue?

How do we best proceed?

As I previously mentioned, the service for the most part works and retrieves the desired results from the TCP connection. It only seems to fail occasionally, but it will eventually fail.

Thanks,
JohnB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few possible causes especially if you are running a high volume of transactions.

1. You can be hitting the WCF connection limit
2. You can be hitting the IIS connection limit
3. Your client may be running out of TCP ports
4. You may have virus scanner acting as a proxy on the client machine and interrupting the connection

Here is some information that may be useful on troubleshooting this issue:

Always start with tracing information to get the big picture:
WCF / ServiceModel
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

System.Net / Network Tracing
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty48b824%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Avoiding TCP/IP Port Exhaustion (BizTalk specific but still applicable)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560610%28v=bts.20%29.aspx

Large Data and Streaming
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

connectionManagement
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb6y0fyc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Hey AgustinCoder: Thanks for the feedback comments. This definitely is not a WCF/IIS issue as this service is hosted as windows service. The errors I'm seeing are on the call to retrieve data from the actual attached device via TCP Client. I will look at firewall/virus scanner issue. I'm wondering if somehow the device is falling asleep?

Comment: It is a possibility.  You may also want to take a look at the TCP port exhaustion issue as it can affect windows services as well as WCF/IIS